# Множество Объектов и перегрузка оператора "<"

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов, set

Имеется вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

using ulli = unsigned long long;
using lli = long long;
using lld = long double;
using usi = unsigned short;

class Atom
{
    friend bool operator <(const Atom& thisis, const Atom& other);
private:
    lld x, y, z;
public:

Atom(lld x, lld y, lld z)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}

void Print()
{
    cout << this->x << " " << this->y << " " << this->z << endl;
}
}

bool operator <(const Atom& thisis, const Atom& other)
{
    return sqrt(thisis.x * thisis.x + thisis.y * thisis.y + thisis.z * thisis.z) < sqrt(other.x * other.x + other.y * other.y + other.z * other.z);
}

int main()
{
    set <Atom> st
    {
        Atom(2.813, 2.813, 2.8135),
            Atom(0, 0, 0),
            Atom(2.813, 0, 0),
            Atom(0, 2.813, 0),
            Atom(2.813, 2.813, 0),
            Atom(0, 0, 2.813),
            Atom(2.813, 0, 2.813),
            Atom(0, 2.813, 2.813),
            Atom(1.4065, 1.4065, 1.4065)
    };
    for (auto elem : st) elem.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге выводиться всего 5 элементов множества, хотя загружается 9. Насколько я понял, ошибка происходит на этапе распределения в set элементов при помощи перегруженного оператора, а значит я как-то неправильного его перегрузил, но что не так понять не могу. Изначально сделал перегрузку в самом классе, но вылазила ошибка, что как бы set не видит этой перегрузки. Скажите как сделать это правильнее. Я новичок, так что не бейте.

Comment: `Atom(2.813, 2.813, 0)` и ` Atom(2.813, 0, 2.813)` равны друг другу , с точки зрения выбранной вами метрики. Поэтому set отбрасывает эквивалентные, с его точки зрения элементы.

Comment: Можно ли как-то это исправить, не меняя реализации сортировки?

Comment: @ ВладимирПопов Можно, если отказаться от set... : std::multiset, если ненужно отбрасывать повторы, или vector если сортировка в контейнере ненужна совсем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, `a = Atom(2.813, 0, 0)` и `b = Atom(0, 2.813, 0)`.

У вас `a < b == false` и `b < a == false`, поэтому `set` считает `a` и `b` одинаковыми, и отказывается вставлять `b`, если `a` уже присутствует.

Правильно - использовать лексикографическое сравнение. Например так:

```
if (a.x < b.x) return true;
if (a.x > b.x) return false;
if (a.y < b.y) return true;
if (a.y > b.y) return false;
if (a.z < b.z) return true;
if (a.z > b.z) return false;
return false;
```

Или, в С++20 делают так:

```
friend auto operator<=>(const Atom &, const Atom &) = default;
```

Это автоматически генерирует правильные `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`.

---

> Изначально сделал перегрузку в самом классе, но вылазила ошибка, что как бы set не видит этой перегрузки.

Должно работать и так и так. Если интересно - покажите ошибку.

---

Еще, если бы вы вдруг хотели оставить текущее поведение, стоило бы убрать `sqrt(...)`, который все равно не влияет на ответ.

Comment: Ошибка C2678 бинарный "<": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "const _Ty" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
Реализовываю вот так внутри класса в public:

bool operator <(const Atom& other)
{
return sqrt(this->x * this->x + this->y * this->y + this->z * this->z) < sqrt(other.x * other.x + other.y * other.y + other.z * other.z);
}

Comment: @ВладимирПопов Забыт `const` перед `{`.

Comment: Можете пояснить зачем он нужен и что делает в этом месте? Также видел, что пишут иногда noexcept. Расскажите вкратце, если не сложно, или дайте ссылку где посмотреть.

Comment: @ВладимирПопов В этом месте `const` относится к левому операнду (то что во friend-е называлось `const Atom& thisis`). Без const там получается что-то типа `Atom& thisis`. Про `noexcept` должно легко гуглиться; и он очень редко бывает нужен.